# I am getting strange characters in the output file of my code

Tags: c, utf-8, compilation, utf-16, fileoutputstream

I get normal results for the output on  the console on dev-c++, but the code writes stange characters, namely UTF16-LE format, into the a_b_768.txt file.  The weird thing is: When I do the same file output procedure for another code, I got normal(UTF8) results in the file, without any problems.

Why am I getting UTF16 output file for one code and  UTF8 for another code, for the output file? The compiler is the same, headers are the same and procedure is the same, but one code writes UTF 16 and another writes UTF8 on the file. I am just adding the code with the problem below:

How can I fix this? Is there any way to modify the code to get UTF8  output in my file?

```
#include <time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[768];
    int b[768];
    int i;
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////writing into a_b_768.txt
    FILE *outFile;
    outFile = fopen("a_b_768.txt", "w");

    if (outFile == NULL){
        printf("Cannot Open File\n");
        exit (0);
    }   

    for ( i = 0;i < 768;++i)
    {
        a[i]=rand()%3;
        fprintf(outFile,"%d ", a[i]);
    }   
    
    //fprintf(outFile,"\n\n");
    for ( i = 0;i < 768;++i)
    {
        b[i]=rand()%3;
        fprintf(outFile,"%d ", b[i]);
    }
    
    // fprintf(outFile,"\n\n\n\n");
    fclose(outFile);
    
    ///////////////////////////////////printing on console
    for ( i = 0;i < 768;++i)
    {
        a[i]=rand()%3;
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }   
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for ( i = 0;i < 768;++i)
    {
        b[i]=rand()%3;
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: not enough info, follow guidelines how to ask please. Also you use formatted output and there is no standard utf-8\16 support for such that, only platform-dependant, but you avoided to mention what platform and compiler you're using.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with this issue.  This is likely an environment issue.  What operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: Check compiler settings

Comment: You are only writing 0, 1 and 2 to the file, I can't see how this can be related to character encoding.

Comment: @Jason I am using Windows 10 Pro and Dev-C++ compiler enviroment.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi which part of the settings I need to  correct?

Comment: @anastaciu did you run the code and get readable results on the output file? (not the console)

Comment: I hadn't, but I have now, the characters in the file are all 0, 1 and 2, as expected.

Comment: Also to note that Dev-C++ is quite old, 2015 old, and it uses an equaly old compiler by default, you may want to use a more modern IDE or at the very least update your gcc version, if you haven't already.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie if it is platform dependent than why am I getting readable output for one code and unreadable for another code? They both are run in the same platform and the code is very similar? The problematic one, which is above, prints onto file in UTF16-LE format and it is not readable, whereas the other code output is printed in a  readable way, i.e.,  in UTF 8 format. Also  could you please explain what the "formatted output" is? I have no idea that I am using it, I don't even know the definition of formatted output.

Comment: @anastaciu I am not a computer science student so I don't have technical details of the compilers. Could you please help me on updating the gcc version ? How can I set it on Dev C++? Or can you advice me a more modern IDE that I can use on Windows?

Comment: Look into Visual Studio 2019 Community it's free, comes with it's own compiler, it's ready to use out of the box, you can also change the default compiler to clang or gcc (see MSdocs online). To keep DevC++ and update the compiler you can download a simple installer here https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/articles/2020-03/9.2.0-release and install it, ideally, if you can, update the version you already have if that possibility is presented. If not, `Tools -> Compiler Options` and change it in the dropdown. This is not guaranteed to fix your issue, but will improve your develpment environment.

Comment: @anastaciu thanks this helped a lot.